# Python Slack bot is not authorized to post to a channel only when running from the Crontab

Tags: python, linux, cron, slack, slack-api

I have successfully setup a Slack bot to message specific public channels. However, it simply refuses to work from the Linux crontab, due to apparently being unauthorized (**despite being authorized when running outside of the crontab**)

For testing purposes, I have set up a very simple barebones script:

```
import sys
import os
from slack.web.client import WebClient

sys.stderr = open("slackbot_errorinfo.txt", "w")
sys.stout = open("slackbot_output.txt", "w")

print("Slackbot test printed info")
slack_client = WebClient(os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"))
response = slack_client.chat_postMessage(channel="testing", text="slackbot test message")
print(response)
```

When I execute this script directly in the terminal, the message gets successfully delivered to the desired slack channel. E.g. like so:

```
python3 /home/Username/Desktop/slacktest.py
```

However, I then test using the exact same command within the crontab, e.g. :

```
33 12 03 01 * python3 /home/Username/Desktop/slacktest.py
```

In the above case, the message does not get delivered, and I receive the following error in the `"slackbot_errorinfo.txt"` standard error file:

> ````
> "/home/Username/Desktop/slacktest.py", line 10, in <module>
>     response = slack_client.chat_postMessage(channel="testing", text="slackbot test message")   File
> "/home/Username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slack/web/client.py",
> line 1077, in chat_postMessage
>     return self.api_call("chat.postMessage", json=kwargs)   File "/home/Username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slack/web/base_client.py",
> line 150, in api_call
>     return self._sync_send(api_url=api_url, req_args=req_args)   File "/home/Username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slack/web/base_client.py",
> line 248, in _sync_send
>     additional_headers=headers,   File "/home/Username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slack/web/base_client.py",
> line 377, in _urllib_api_call
>     use_sync_aiohttp=False,   File "/home/Username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slack/web/slack_response.py",
> line 194, in validate
>     raise e.SlackApiError(message=msg, response=self) slack.errors.SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed. The
> server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'not_authed'}```
> ````

I don't understand how the bot can be authorized when executing the script in a normal command line, but *not* when using the the same script in the crontab.

I have already confirmed that:

- The Python interpreter/executable being used is the same in both cases (it is `/usr/bin/python3` in both normal command line and crontab
- The output of `os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN")` gives the same key in both cases

If anyone would be able to help explain this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If this is in /etc/crontab, it is running as root and has no idea what your environment variables are.

Comment: if there's no PATH in the environment variables then you will have to absolute-path the executable(s), possibly 
/usr/bin/python3